# Jenkins Build Folder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins Job which I execute using Build parameters. My Requirement is to have a single build Folder(i.e if I execute my job 'n' number of times today it should create a single build folder with date as postfix to the folder ) rather than separate build folder for each build.Is it possible? Is there any plugin that can help me to achieve this? Please Help

Comment: Can you expand on why you want to do this ?  The build folder is really an implementation detail, as normally you'd access build data via Jenkins' UI or API.

Comment: We execute the job many times.So just wanted to have a single build folder for jobs that are executed on particular day.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to store today's date

```
set "day=%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%"
```

Test the variable expansion

```
echo today's date is[dd/mm/yyyy]:%day%
```

Now create a folder with today's date :

```
mkdir %day%
```

The above command would create a folder with today's date and in second run you would have this directory already created so the command output would be message stating "directory already exists."

Now to use jenkins pre-defined variable to create another folder which will store your code inside today's folder

```
cd %day%
mkdir %BUILD_NUMBER%
```

Now change your directory to the path of newly created path to store your code :

```
cd %BUILD_NUMBER%
<<store your build code/artifacts Here..>>
```

Please Note that Build_number is a jenkins pre-defined variable which will hold the value of current build number.

Now you can store all builds done in a particular day under one path

if you face any issue , we can certainly make some tweaks to get it right ..

Comment: Artifacts are still getting stored in the Jenkins workspace build Folder.How to store it in the newly created folder

Comment: @RCBian how do you checkout code from version control ?